# XLamp XHP70.2 LEDs Configuration issue

Tags: voltage, led, datasheet, configuration

I was reading the [XHP70](https://assets.cree-led.com/a/ds/x/XLamp-XHP70.2.pdf) LEDs datasheet where there were two configurations given, 6V and 12V. I am having a confusion whether a single led is rated 6V/12V or a combination of LEDs are rated this way as shown in the diagram below:

[image]

Is this the internal diagram of a single LED having 4 LEDs or these are separate 4 leds where if used in 12V configuration each has a 3V drop across it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A white LED *<sup>it's generally a blue LED with filter actually but let's ignore this for now</sup>* has a forward voltage of 2.8~3.2 V.

The LED you are referring to (XHP70) has 4 LED chips inside a single package, and the diagrams you put show the internal connections of these chips *(the zener diodes are ESD protection diodes)*.

So a single XHP70 has two "individual LED branches" *(named as A and B of which the terminals are named as positive A and positive B, respectively)*, each branch consisting of two LED chips connected in series, therefore having a forward voltage of 6V.

If you connect these individuals in parallel, total forward voltage for a single XHP70 will be 6V. If you connect these individuals in series, total forward voltage for a single XHP70 will be 12V.

---

Today it's the common way for the manufacturers to put multiple chips in a single package and connect them in series/parallel combinations for the target voltage (e.g. COB "chip-on-board" LEDs). You can see, for example, 54V white LEDs which are actually having 18 chips connected in series in a single package. If you look carefully you can see the individual chips.

[image]